# What is the Big O of this implementaition

Tags: c++, algorithm, big-o, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to answer a question on leetcode https://leetcode.com/problems/palindromic-substrings/. I know the passing solution is an O(N^2) solution with dynamic programming. All the solutions I've seen have used a bottom-up approach. I tried to use a top-down approach and I thought I also accomplished O(N^2) but the online judge is giving me time limit exceeded error at the final test case which made me unsure if my implementation is indeed O(N^2). Can someone please tell me the correct big O of the below code?

```
bool dfs(string s, int start, int end, string curWord, int &count, unordered_map<string, int> &map)
{
    if (start >= end)
    {
        return true;
    }
    string st = to_string(start) + " , " + to_string(end);
    if (map.find(st) != map.end())
        return map[st];

    if (s[start] == s[end] && dfs(s, start + 1, end - 1, curWord, count, map))
    {
        count++;
        map[st] = true;
    }
    else
    {
        map[st] = false;
    }
    return map[st];
}

int countSubstrings(string s)
{
    string word = "";
    int count = 0;
    unordered_map<string, int> map;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = s.length() - 1; j > i; j--)
        {
            dfs(s, i, j, word, count, map);
        }
    }
    return count + s.length();
}
```

Comment: I notice that you never set `map[st] = false` when you find a *non*-palindromic substring. Is that intentional?

Comment: it was not intentional, and I just fixed it. But it still doesn't pass the question

Comment: a reminder: `bool dfs(const string &s, ...` would make it a little faster.

Comment: This time it passed the final test case, but submission still gave a time out error saying "130 / 130 test cases passed, but took too long." Is my Big O actually O(N^2) or am i wrong

Comment: another one: `if(auto it = map.find(st); it !=map.end()) return it->second;` and `it->second=true;` and `return it->second;`

Comment: this one did not improve the speed that much i think

Comment: countSubstrings is clearly O(n^2) because it has nested for loops.  That means dfs must be O(1) but I don't think it is - it looks like it recurses which would make it some non constant value.

Comment: by the way, it's not O(n2) i guess. countSubStrings runs n*(n+1)/2 times and each dfs call from countSubStrings runs n/2 times. making the overall time O(n3)

Comment: and yet another one: `unordered_map<string, int> &map` is an overkill. question says n will be less than 1000. so you could use int32 as the key values. high half int16 stores start and the low one stores the end. thus the map becomes <int32, bool>. hence, you get rid of string.

Comment: @seleciii44 how do you know each dfs call runs n/2 times? I used dp for it to have an early exit and thougth amortized time for dfs would be O(1)

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I thought the dfs function would have an amortized time of O(1) because I used dp to store the previous values, can you explain why this is wrong because I can't figure it out.

Comment: @OgiciBumKacar here: `if (s[start] == s[end] && dfs(s, start + 1, end - 1, curWord, count, map))`. each time you call dfs with two element less. making n/2 times at most

Comment: @seleciii44 yes but as you see before that I have the dynamic programming condition of map.find() for early exit, so once a value is set it never recurses past that. In my theory dfs function should run O(2N) times total and O(1) amortized so total runtime with countSubstrings should be O(N^2)

Comment: sorry, I didn't check the code thoroughly the first time. Your code seems O(N^2). On the other hand, I don't see a reason for the curWord argument. Remove that, and change the map into <int32, bool> and try again.

Comment: It's at best O(N^2 logN), because the key construction in `dfs` is O(log N). But I guess your code is failing because it's just very inefficient at what it does. Avoid the unordered_map, and just use an array of size N*N.

Comment: I don't see why you need dynamic programming to solve this problem in O(N^2). For each center point of a potential palindome (of which there are 2N+1), you can try expanding the palindrome around that center up to N times. That's O(N^2) time and O(1) space, and simple code.

Comment: you pass string not by reference hence needlessly increasing complexity to O(n^3), instead of cutting string for each dfs call try passing string by reference, and in map saving not [string,result] pairs but [(startIndex, endIndex),int] pairs

Comment: @Photon I've updated the string to be a reference per selecii44's comment, it sped up a lot but didn't change the time limit problem. But changing my map design did help and passed the tests. Thank you

Comment: @PaulHankin you are correct it is possible to do it that way, but I was using this problem to practice my DP abilities.

Comment: @PaulHankin using an array of size N*N worked. thank you.

Comment: @seleciii44 with your suggestions and PaulHankins N*N array suggestion it passed the tests. thank you.